# How to make an "ASCII" art table for Facebook or Twitter?

Tags: fonts, ascii-art

How to have a table on services that only support plain text like Facebook or Twitter, since they are all misaligned for not having a mono-spaced typeface? In other words, how to turn this:

╔═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║               Col1                ║    Col2    ║ NumCol ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ Value 1                           ║ Value 2    ║    123 ║
║ This is a row with only one cell  ║            ║        ║
║ This row is testing html entities ║ Te
st ║     45 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════╩════════╝

to this:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════════╦════════════╦════════╗
║               Col1                ║    Col2    ║ NumCol ║
╠═══════════════════════════════════╬════════════╬════════╣
║ Value 1                           ║ Value 2    ║    123 ║
║ This is a row with only one cell  ║            ║        ║
║ This row is testing html entities ║ Te<br />st ║     45 ║
╚═══════════════════════════════════╩════════════╩════════╝
```

?

<sup>FYI: [Is there a web app to create ASCII art tables? - Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/6700/63572)</sup>

Comment: ASCII art needs mono-spaced fonts, or at least predictable fonts, to work. It was good in the 80's when all fonts were mono-spaced... & should be left there...

Comment: I have the same question. I bet it's possible. http://qaz.wtf/u/convert.cgi and http://slothsoft.net/UnicodeMapper/?lang=en-us look like cool tools, but I haven't quite figured out the monospacing for space characters yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The table is misaligned because it requires mono-spacing. Mono-spaced fonts are not used by Twitter and Facebook, but you may be able to replace the text with corresponding unicode fixed-width characters. This is not technically mono-spaced, characters are not necessarily positioned in alignment with a fixed grid and to my knowledge, there is no fullwidth equivalent for characters like the space, but the predictable spacing may make it a lot easier to create a decent looking table nonetheless.

The unicode block for halfwidth and fullwidth characters is U+FF00 to U+FFEF and text written in those characters ﻿ｌｏｏｋｓ  ｌｉｋｅ  ｔｈｉｓ. You may want to use a tool to convert text automaticaly, such as [this one](http://www.linkstrasse.de/en/%EF%BD%86%EF%BD%95%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%8C%EF%BD%97%EF%BD%89%EF%BD%84%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%88%EF%BC%8D%EF%BD%83%EF%BD%8F%EF%BD%8E%EF%BD%96%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%92%EF%BD%94%EF%BD%85%EF%BD%92). The linked page also has some interesting background reading on the purpose of this set of characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.  Doing so requires the use of a fixed-width font, and there's no way to force that on Facebook or Twitter clients.

You also can't make use of HTML <TABLE>s, either, since there's no provision for specifying/entering them.

Comment: So is there any way to establish a table in Facebook or Twitter without adding an image?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  <TABLE>s have a history of being abused by griefers in comment/discussion fora to ruin the page layout to the point of unusability, so it's not entirely surprising they're not supported.

Comment: Ａｒｅ  ｙｏｕ  ｓｕｒｅ  ｔｈｅｒｅ＇ｓ  ｎｏ  ｗａｙ  ｔｏ  ｆｏｒｃｅ  ｔｅｘｔ  ｔｏ  ｂｅ  ｒｅｎｄｅｒｅｄ  ｍｏｎｏ－ｓｐａｃｅｄ？

Comment: @ewhac. Griefers, the players who irritate other players? Why they do that? I can't see any connection to the table.